# Garbled characters from micro-controller

Tags: microcontroller

I have ATMEGA328P-PU micro-controller connected to POLOLU - PMG03A programmer. I'm using the following code to send data:

```
#define F_CPU     1600000UL
#define BAUD      19200
#define BRC       ((F_CPU/16/BAUD) - 1)

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <util/setbaud.h> 

int main( void ) 
{
    UBRR0H = (BRC >> 8);    
    UBRR0L = BRC;

    UCSR0B = ( 1 << TXEN0 );
    UCSR0C = ( 1 << UCSZ01 ) | ( 1 << UCSZ00 );

    while( 1 )
    {
        UDR0 = 0B11110000;
        _delay_ms(100);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

but instead of receiving '11110000' in /dev/ttyACM0, I receive '11111000'.

```
0000037e: 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000  ......
00000384: 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000  ......
0000038a: 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000  ......
00000390: 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000  ......
00000396: 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000  ......
0000039c: 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000 11111000  ......
```

In addition the byte values change sometimes. Why is this happening?

Comment: What does the waveform look like on the scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By experimenting I found out that I had to change BAUD rate to 14400 and it worked:

```
  #define BAUD    14400
```

Comment: At 133% the speed of 14400, that explains a consistent single bit difference. Every 5th bit would be wrong.

Comment: That said, your microcontoller AND your terminal program must be at the same baud to work (Auto-detect doesn't always work either). So it's likely that hyperterminal/putty/whatever you were using was not set to 19200 baud either. Double check it's current setting.